# What does "it" refer to in "... political stability makes it likely that..."?

Tags: pronouns

What does "it" refer to in the following sentence?

> Increased food prices will stimulate greater investment in food production, but the critical importance of food to human well-being and also to social and political stability makes **it** likely that governments and other organizations will want to encourage food production beyond that driven by simple market mechanisms 75 (Skidelsky, 2009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'It' refers to what follows it. That is, the fact that "governments and other organizations will want to encourage food production beyond that driven by simple market mechanisms."